# string to list slice in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible 2.2

I want to get to the slices of the below variable, how would I do so ?

`hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_hostname']|list`

basically I have a hostname, `hostname001` that I wish to retrieve the last two characters on.

How do I split it and slice it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `ansible_hostname[-3:]`.

Why do you use `hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_hostname']` instead of simply `ansible_hostname`?

For strings and lists you may use Python slicing technics.